# How to restrict users after login

Tags: laravel-5

How can i restrict different users after they login so they wont access directories that they are not supposed to? That means everybody should access only their directories
here is my login controller

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        foreach ($this->guard()->user()->roles as $role) {
            if ($role->name=='Admin') {
                return redirect('issuer');
            }else if ($role->name=='Approver') {
                return redirect('approver');
            }else if ($role->name=='Issuer')
            {
                return redirect('issuer');
            }else if ($role->name=='Requester')
            {
                return redirect('requester');
            }
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('login');
    }
```

here is my user Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','active',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_users');
    }
```

Here is my Role Model

```
 protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_users');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code i found that your using roles, same as roles make directory to specific access level's. For example name access levels like low-level, mid level, high-level and then specify each user to their respective access level. According to there access level hide and visible the directory.